# Solr Synonyms Issue

Tags: solr, synonym, solr-schema

I have configured synonyms as per my requirements but is only points for single words.

Example: If I search for **TV**, it showing results related to **Television**, because **TV => Television** set in synonyms.

But what if someone search **shop keeper** which is actually as **shopkeeper** in documents.

I have documents which are results of **shopkeeper** word. So, when someone search for **shopkeeper**, it shows results. But when someone searches for **shop keeper**, it does not showing results related to **shopkeeper** word. I have so many words like this in all the fields of all the collections.

I have tried by expanding this while indexing by

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
```

but it does not working.

How can I set synonyms with whitespace?

Comment: please add your problems in the question, now question is incomplete

Comment: what's not working now? show an example of the query, that is not working, do not be afraid to be more precise

Comment: why you adding it into comments? move it to the question, so people will see your problem easier, than just looking through comments

Comment: [A possibly helpful link](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/10/27/why-is-multi-term-synonyms-so-hard-in-solr/). What does your `synonyms` file look like?

Comment: Thanks... It helps me ... !!